# Take Delay on HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am using `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` to connect on the other PHP link from Dot Net to POST some data from .Net to PHP. But its worked fine the first two times when the control come to the line "Stream newrStream = myrRequest.GetRequestStream();" and taking delay for some second from third time onwards.How to slove this problem.

My coding is:

```
ASCIIEncoding Encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
     string postDat = "Name=xxx";
     byte[] datas = Encode.GetBytes(postDat);

HttpWebRequest myrRequest = HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.xxx.php");
            myrRequest.Method = "POST";
            myrRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            myrRequest.ContentLength = datas.Length;
            Stream newrStream = myrRequest.GetRequestStream();

            // Send the data.
            newrStream.Write(datas, 0, datas.Length);
            newrStream.Close();
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: how to reduce the delay time

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to keep in mind is to review the URI, parameters and headers being sent, specifically:

1. Reserved characters. Send reserved characters by the URI can bring
   problems  `! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? # [ ]`
2. URI Length: You should not exceed 2000 characters
3. Length headers:Most web servers do limit size of headers they
   accept. For example in Apache default limit is 8KB.

Keep in mind that if you want to send data from a longer length is recommended to send in the body of the message:

```
    string uri = string.Format("https://my-server.com/api/document?queryParameter={1}", "value");
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.Method = "POST";
    string data = "Some data"; //Body data
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(data);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    Stream GETResponseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GETResponseStream);
    var response = sr.ReadToEnd(); //Response
    resp.Close(); //Close response
    sr.Close(); //Close StreamReader
```